# How Android handles "called from wrong thread" exception

Tags: java, android, user-interface, background

I'm curious how Android can handle situation when worker thread tries to change something on UI. My guess is that there is some queue of messages (but different one from UI queue wich is managed by handler + looper) and the system checks thread id when tries to post a message. So, I'll be highly appreciate for any hints.

Comment: Looking at one of those stacktraces it appears that all calls that modify a `View` end up in the `ViewRootImpl` class which is *The top of a view hierarchy, implementing the needed protocol between View and the WindowManager.* In that class a check is made for the thread identity.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your answer. You can convert your comment into an answer and I'll accept it as a right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at one of those stacktraces it appears that all calls that modify(invalidating the `View` and making it to need a redraw) a `View` ends up in the `android.view.ViewRootImpl` class which is:

*The top of a view hierarchy, implementing the needed protocol between View and the WindowManager.*

In that class, before the change of the view is allowed, a check is made for the thread identity using the `getThread()` method.